# SVG animation of a thick dashed rounded shadowed line over an arbitrary background

Tags: svg, css-animations

I am trying to create an animation of a dashed line over an arbitrary (e. g. not known in advance, not necessarily constant) background - let's say, a photograph. I want the dashes to be thick and rounded at the ends. I also want them to be outlined with a different color, so they are visible regardless of the background.

My initial googling gave me [this example](https://codepen.io/dlittle/pen/dprEL/). From what I understand, first it draws "anti-dashes", so to speak, of the background color, then animates a solid line being drawn under them. Obviously, that won't do what I want: no way to make the ends rounded, no way to outline each entire dash, and, most importantly, it requires a constant background.

I tried a different approach: drew the required curve, with all its thickness, roundness, shadows etc., then used an animated solid line as a visibility mask. Basically, it does what I want, except for possible self-intersections of the curve (see the "artifact" at the self-intersection point on the animation below).

Is it possible to fix that somehow? (just in case, [the same code at codepen](https://codepen.io/lazunin/pen/oMdgxv/))

```js
function init()
{
 //some "magic numbers" to make a smooth curve
 var to_draw = "M23.742,10.709 c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631 c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201 c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354 c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591";
 
 //set the same base line for all three paths
 ["line", "shadow", "hide"].forEach(
 (element, index, array) =>
 {
  document.getElementById(element).setAttribute('d', to_draw);
 });
 
 //get the lenght of the resulting curve
 var path = document.querySelector('.line');
 var length = path.getTotalLength();
 
 //set the dash length to cover the entire curve
 //
 //set the offset so that our long dash is initially off the curve,
 //then it slides along the curve when the CSS animation plays
 var elem = document.querySelector(".hide"); 
 elem.style.strokeDasharray = length;
 elem.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
}
```

```css
.base
{
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-dasharray: 10, 20;
 fill: none;
}

.line
{
 stroke: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
 stroke-width: 5;
}

.shadow
{
 stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 stroke-width: 7;
}

.hide
{
 stroke: white;
 stroke-width: 8;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-dasharray: 0;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 animation: dash 3s linear alternate infinite;
 fill: none;
}

@keyframes dash
{
 to
 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body onload = "init()">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<circle cx="230" cy="150" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
<mask id = "theMask">
 <path id = "hide" class = "hide" />
</mask>
 
<path id = "shadow" class = "base shadow" mask = "url(#theMask)" />
  
<path id = "line" class = "base line" mask = "url(#theMask)" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with crossings, you will need to break the line up into two or more sections and animate them sequentially.

So in your case, you would need two lines. One from the start of the path, that goes past the intersection. Then a second one that starts where the first one ends and crosses back over the first one.

Your case is complicated a little further by the fact that you have dashed lines.  If you are not careful, you will be able to see where the second line begins, because the dash pattern will restart abruptly.  To deal with that you will either have to:

1. Split the line at a length that coincides with a point where the dash pattern repeats, or
2. Give the second line a dash offset that matches the point in the dash pattern that the first line was when it ended.